# Wired Apex for LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am hoping a better JS developer can explain to me why one of these methods fails and the other works.  I have some wired Apex to get data into an LWC. If I used a tracked property and  'this.property = data'. I would get an undefined error.

But if I call the info directly from the wired property everything works. The Salesforce documentation seems to be telling me to give the data to a trackable property. [Wired Apex Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about)

Where is my JS that throws an undefined error going wrong?

Here is my JS that works

```
import {LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import getBenchmarkValues from '@salesforce/apex/BenchmarksSelector.getOverAllBenchmarks';

export default class OverAllBenchmarks2 extends LightningElement {


  @wire(getBenchmarkValues)benchmarks;
}
```

HTML That works

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Overall Benchmark Values">
        <template for:each={benchmarks.data}  for:item='benchmark'>
            <p key={benchmark.id}>Program Delivery Rate <span>{benchmark.Program_Mean_Delivery_Rate__c}%</span></p>
            <p key={benchmark.id}>Hello This is a test</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS that fails

```
import {LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import getBenchmarkValues from '@salesforce/apex/BenchmarksSelector.getOverAllBenchmarks';

export default class OverAllBenchmarks extends LightningElement {
    @track benchmarks;

    @wire(getBenchmarkValues)wiredBenchmark({data, error}){
        if(data){this.benchmarks = data}
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this.benchmarks);
    }
}
```

HTML That Fails

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Overall Benchmark Values">
        <template for:each={benchmarks.data}  for:item='benchmark'>
            <p key={benchmark.id}>Program Delivery Rate <span>{benchmark.Program_Mean_Delivery_Rate__c}%</span></p>
            <p>Hello</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the second JS, HTML is you have defined `benchmarks` as

```
if(data){this.benchmarks = data}
```

So you should be accessing it in HTML like

```
<template>
    <template if:true={benchmarks}>
    <lightning-card title="Overall Benchmark Values">
        <template for:each={benchmarks}  for:item='benchmark'>
            <p key={benchmark.id}>Program Delivery Rate <span>{benchmark.Program_Mean_Delivery_Rate__c}%</span></p>
            <p>Hello</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
    </template>
</template>
```

rather than `{benchmarks.data}`, because there is nothing like `data` in `benchmarks`.

Comment: I made those updates but I still get an error that 'Program_Mean_Delivery_Rate__c is undefined'

Comment: @BrooksJohnson please check the updated code. The null check was missing added that

Comment: Am I looking in the wrong place? Not seeing any updated with a null check.

Comment: @BrooksJohnson this = `<template if:true={benchmarks}>`

Comment: Perfect,  Assuming the null check just stops the Component from loading before the wire method has returned data?